# residuals in the simple regression model

Tags: regression, residuals, sum

The residuals in the simple regression model have to sum up to 0?

Comment: It's true if you use least squares.

Comment: isn't it always true?

Comment: In practice, yes.  In the abstract, it depends upon the loss function used to determine the parameter estimates; you could construct a loss function with a huge penalty for any negative error at all and a small penalty for a positive error, which might lead to all errors being $\geq 0$.

Comment: thank you so much! Could you try to help me and in my other question i have posted? i am struggling with that

Comment: Please don't attempt to recruit answerers to your other questions in comments.

Answer (score 4):

> The residuals in the simple regression model can not have the same sign, because the sum of the residuals must be equal to 0, right?

With ordinary least squares, this is indeed the case $-$ that the residuals sum to zero $-$ so they clearly cannot all have the same sign. It's certainly possible to have $n-2$ residuals of one sign and $2$ of the other. One interesting question is whether you can have fewer than two residuals with one of the signs but I suspect you can't avoid having at least two. [With regression through the origin, you could get it down to one, though.]

As jbowman suggests if you move away from least squares and (say) consider simple quantile regression, then it is possible to get a case where no residuals have one of the signs (e.g. no negative residuals).